# $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] через  (PHP,JavaScript,PERL)

Tags: php, javascript, perl

Есть вот такой вот код

`<script src="http://zzzzz.zz/`**script.php**`" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Я его могу пометить на любой сайт, даже с другим доменом

Вопрос в следующем

Допустим я поместил код что написал выше на сайт yyyyy.yy
теперь при загрузке сайта yyyyy.yy автоматически грузится файл script.php который находится на другом домене

как мне из **script.php** определить откуда пришел посетитель на сайт yyyyy.yy ?

Если допустим я буду использовать $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] то получу страницу на сайте yyyyy.yy на которой запустился этот скрипт.

Как быть?
Может как то можно через javascript который сгенерирует script.php ?
Или может через Perl это можно как то решить?

Comment: Так в чем вопрос-то ?

Comment: вопрос в том как получить $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] с сайта yyyyy.yy 

т.е. узнать с какой страницы пришел посетитель на сайт yyyyy.yy через script.php

script.php находится на другом домене


для тех кто все равно не понял
как счетчики посещений узнают с каких страниц пользователи поподают на сайт ведь $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] указывает всегда на сайт на котором установлен счетчик

Comment: куки, + на мой взгляд они делают запись на сайт с которого пришел пользователь а не на Вашем.

Я замечал, что если я перешел по ссылке на сайте, на котором НЕ стоит метрика и некоторые яндексовские виджеты, на сайт на котором стоит метрика, то в http://metrika.yandex.ru/list/ я вижу только неизвестный источник

Comment: фигню написали
кукисами может позволить себе пользоваться только гугл
потому что он еще отслеживает через аваст, через скайп, через хром
(вот мы и дошли до причины почему гугл рекламит хром и всю свою лабуду)
у яндекса такого нет

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте: `window.parent.document.referrer` не уверен, но по логике, мне кажется, что должно работать

Comment: Либо: document.URL

Answer (score 0):

```
$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]
```

Comment: в JS: document.URL

Answer (score 0):

Что сложного то

```
<script src="http://zzzzz.zz/script.php?from=<адрес сайта либо хардкодом либо на js>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

в результате в php получаете `$_GET['from']`

Comment: честно я в шоке с "советов" некоторых граждан здесь :)

Answer (score -1):

Вместо script.php используйте JS.
Чтото типа `<script src="http://zzzzz.zz/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`
А из него отправляйте даные к себе аяксом.
Имеено так работают счетчики посещений насколько я знаю.